# Rename azure sql database using powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-sql-database

I've created azure database using powershell. Now i want to rename the database using powershell. My purpose to do this is creating temporary database, then deploy database release to temp DB,then rename production db to any other name, finaly rename Temp Db to production db

Comment: For AzureRM command, the -NewName parameter doesn't exists anymore. But not sure if the rename is feasible as per new feature.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To achieve this, you can use the cmdlet "Set-AzureSqlDatabase", the parameter "-NewDatabaseName" permits to set a new name for a specified database name.

```
Set-AzureSqlDatabase -ServerName 'myservername' -DatabaseName 'mydb' -NewDatabaseName 'newNameForTheDb'
```

Here is the documentation : https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/dn546732.aspx

Comment: If you want to use an AzureRM command, use the following syntax:

Set-AzureRMSqlDatabase -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ServerName $SQLServerName -DatabaseName $DatabaseName -NewName $NewDatabaseName

Comment: Command is outdated. It is now: Set-AzSqlDatabase. Also NewDatabaseName is now -NewName

Answer (score 10):

using Az.Sql module the command command would be:

```
Set-AzSqlDatabase -DatabaseName <sourceDbName> -NewName <targetDbName> -ServerName <server1> -ResourceGroupName <resgroup1>
```